# Are there any ugra form of god Vishnu besides Narsimha, declared so in the scriptures?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, shilpa-shastras

The depiction of god Narsimha is known to be an ugra (fierce) form of Vishnu generally, specifically in reference to him protecting Prahalada?

Do scriptures list or refer to any other manifestations of Vishnu as 'ugra'?

Or is Narsimha is only listed the ugra form of god Vishnu?

Comment: Vishnu is any form is angry, His eyes are described as the sun and the moon, one being angry and other being kind, even Narasimha is only Ugra to Hiranyakashipu and not to anyone else, he said "Prahalada, I am only angry at your father, Don't fear me I am very kind to everyone else", Also if you want an angry form of him, you have Parashurama, who is an angry Brahmin

Comment: No. Vishnu is saumya generally. In the Silpasastra we have Ugra form and Saumya form type of murtis

Comment: Still even though he is saumya he is angry when it comes to following Dharma in any avatar

Comment: Sri Narashimha is always seen as Yoga Narashimha (calm one) when it comes to adharma by Hiranyakashiu, he is seen a fierceful lion or ortherwise he is calm and kind he is seen as a karunamurthi for the ones who believe him

Comment: Pothuraju in South india who is usually considered as Vishnu, sibling of Grama devis (Amsas of Parvati), is ugra too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

The Kāmika-Āgama (one of the 28 principle Śaivāgamas), lists three forms of Viṣṇu (including Nṛsiṃha) as Ugra-forms or fierce forms.

> (२६. ग्रामादि देवतास्थान विधिः)
>
> > [Chapter
> > 26](https://archive.org/details/kamika-agama-purva-pada-part-1/page/n409/mode/2up?view=theater),
> > Pūrvapād, Kāmika-Āgama
>
> ईशविष्ण्वोस्तु मूर्तिस्याद् द्विविधा परिकीर्तिता ।
>   उग्रा शान्ता च
> तत्राद्या उग्रकर्मरता मता ॥ २२ ॥
>
> > 22. The divine forms of Śiva and Viṣṇu are of two kinds. They are the subduing forms (ugra mūrti) and the sublime forms (śānta mūrti).
> >     Of these two, the subduing forms are much intent on doing fierce
> >     activities to control the evil forces.
>
> ......
>
> विश्वरूपं नृसिंहं च वटशायिनमेव च ।
>  जामदग्न्यं च जानीयात् उग्रं
> वैष्णवविग्रहम् ॥ २५ ॥
>
> > 25. **The subduing forms (Ugra-forms) of Viṣṇu who once appeared as reposing on the leaf of a fig tree are Viśvarūpa, Nṛsiṃha, and Paraśurāma.**
>
> English Translation by Dr. S.P. Sabharathanam

Therefore, as per the  Kāmika-Āgama, the following three manifestations of God Visnu are depicted as Ugra-Rūpa:

- Viśvarūpa,
- Nṛsiṃha, and
- Paraśurāma

Comment: Could you please tell, the other types of rūpa (other than ugra)? I don't understand why your answer has been downvoted by someone though. I have added one vote.